# Using 3G Modem: works on Firefox Browser but not on Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, modem

I have a really odd problem with a pair of computers in my network:

When the computers try to establish a connection through the 3G modem (Huawei E160, operator: movistar Colombia, South America) **they cannot navigate IF and only IF I use Internet Explorer**. While using firefox the problem doesn't occur. Reinstalling Explorer doesn't work at all. The POP/SMTP connection in Outlook 2007 just works.

Does someone experienced such odd situation and have any solution?

Comment: You may want to check to see if your internet explorer has any proxy settings configured that would be keeping you from access the interwebz

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. I checked everything about my network settings. It down on me that something on Internet Explorer was not working properly and in consequence I installed Firefox. It worked with the same properties that explorer had. This problem is driving me nuts.